# MySQL Sum by Date with Joined Tables

Tags: php, mysql, count, sum

I have 2 different tables, heres the structure of the tables that are used in the query:

`leads`:

```
- id
- date_added
- website
```

`assignments`:

```
- id
- id_lead
- date_assigned
- website
```

What I want to do is count how many rows are in the `leads` and the `assignments` table for each website based on a date range. For example, I want a count for `today` which will give me the total number of rows for `today` per website.

The date range I am looking for is this:

```
Today
Yesterday
2 Days Ago
3 Days Ago
4 Days Ago
5 Days Ago
6 Days Ago
7 Days Ago
This Week
This Month
Last Month
This Year
```

So I want to show a sum or a count of all rows per website.

Here is the query I have already, but it does not count properly, and there is no join in it:

```
select `website`, 
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(`date_assigned`), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_day,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(`date_assigned`), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 1 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_yesterday,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(`date_assigned`), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 2 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_2_days,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(`date_assigned`), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 3 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_3_days,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(`date_assigned`), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 4 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_4_days,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(`date_assigned`), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 5 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_5_days,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(`date_assigned`), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 6 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_6_days,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(`date_assigned`), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 7 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_7_days,
sum(case when YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_assigned`)) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_week, 
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(`date_assigned`), '%Y-%m')= date_format(now(), '%Y-%m') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_month,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(`date_assigned`), '%Y-%m')= date_format(now() - interval 1 month, '%Y-%m') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_last_month,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(`date_assigned`), '%Y')= date_format(now(), '%Y') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_year
from `assignments`
where `id_dealership`!='65' and `id_dealership`!='77' and `id_dealership`!='89'
group by `website`
order by `website` asc
```

Heres the PHP for the query which spits it out into the table format I want:

```
echo '<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="100%">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th class="l">Website</th>';
echo '<th>Today</th>';
echo '<th>Yesterday</th>';
echo '<th>2 Days Ago</th>';
echo '<th>3 Days Ago</th>';
echo '<th>4 Days Ago</th>';
echo '<th>5 Days Ago</th>';
echo '<th>6 Days Ago</th>';
echo '<th>7 Days Ago</th>';
echo '<th>This Week</th>';
echo '<th>This Month</th>';
echo '<th>Last Month</th>';
echo '<th>This Year</th>';
echo '</tr>';

$count = 1;
$c_day_total = 0;
$c_yesterday_total = 0;
$c_2_days_total = 0;
$c_3_days_total = 0;
$c_4_days_total = 0;
$c_5_days_total = 0;
$c_6_days_total = 0;
$c_7_days_total = 0;
$c_week_total = 0;
$c_month_total = 0;
$c_last_month_total = 0;
$c_year_total = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    foreach ($row as $k => $v)
        $$k = htmlspecialchars($v, ENT_QUOTES);

    if (!empty($website))
    {
        $website = '<a href="website.php?url='.$website.'">'.$website.'</a>';
        //$website = '<a href="http://'.$website.'">'.$website.'</a>';

        echo '<tr class="'.(($count % 2) ? 'row1' : 'row2' ).'">';
        echo '<td>'.$website.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$c_day.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$c_yesterday.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$c_2_days.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$c_3_days.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$c_4_days.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$c_5_days.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$c_6_days.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$c_7_days.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$c_week.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$c_month.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$c_last_month.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$c_year.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        $c_day_total = $c_day_total + $c_day;
        $c_yesterday_total = $c_yesterday_total + $c_yesterday;
        $c_2_days_total = $c_2_days_total + $c_2_days;
        $c_3_days_total = $c_3_days_total + $c_3_days;
        $c_4_days_total = $c_4_days_total + $c_4_days;
        $c_5_days_total = $c_5_days_total + $c_5_days;
        $c_6_days_total = $c_6_days_total + $c_6_days;
        $c_7_days_total = $c_7_days_total + $c_7_days;
        $c_week_total = $c_week_total + $c_week;
        $c_month_total = $c_month_total + $c_month;
        $c_last_month_total = $c_last_month_total + $c_last_month;
        $c_year_total = $c_year_total + $c_year;
        $count++;
    }
}

echo '<tr class="'.(($count % 2) ? 'row1' : 'row2' ).'">';
echo '<td>Totals</td>';
echo '<td>'.$c_day_total.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$c_yesterday_total.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$c_2_days_total.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$c_3_days_total.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$c_4_days_total.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$c_5_days_total.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$c_6_days_total.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$c_7_days_total.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$c_week_total.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$c_month_total.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$c_last_month_total.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$c_year_total.'</td>';
echo '</tr>';

echo '</table>';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is datatype of date_assigned column. And also add full create script of both table

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a tip about this part of your SQL query:

```
where `id_dealership`!='65' and `id_dealership`!='77' and `id_dealership`!='89'
```

You can use this code instead:

```
where `id_dealership` NOT IN (65,77,89)
```